# Creating a close button with JS?

Tags: javascript, css, list, button

**Problem:** I'm trying to create a close button and add it to then end of a dynamic list. Is this a fundamentally wrong approach?

**Function**: User clicks it and the list item strikes through. Here is what the code looks like so far with `myList` being the list ID I define in html:

**Code:**

```
    var myNodelist = document.getElementById("myList");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
```

edit: I have gone ahead and tried the `ID` route as shown above. It doesnt work.

FWIW here is my css for the close button

```
.close {
    background-color: #f44336;
  }

.close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Did you create an element named `myList`? Tag names are element names such as `p`, `div`, `span` etc

Comment: Hey @sudo_kaizen. My html file contains ` <ul id="myList">` as the only mention of myList.

getElementsByTagName is the only way I found online to pick that element. Is it wrong?

Comment: User `var myNodelist = document.getElementsById("myList");` instead of `var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("myList");`

Comment: @Frondor Good question, at the end of each list item (that I dynamically create)

Comment: Why are you using `getElementByID`? It is `getElementById`

Comment: @sudo_kaizen That was a typo on my question here. I just fixed it, the code in my editor has the right syntax. Apologies.

Comment: What you claim to be trying to do is different from what you really want to do. You are trying to create a close button and add it to then end of a dynamic list, but what you really want to do is add a button to each list item because from your question, you want the particular list item to be _closed_ when its close button is clicked. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append the `span (close button)` when you create the `li` and add event listener on span to close the `li`. You don't need to iterate over the li list and append the close button.

**Example**

```js
function addItem() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("myList");
    var candidate = document.getElementById("listInput");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id', candidate.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    span.addEventListener('click', () => {
        li.remove();
    });

    li.appendChild(span);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
.close {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
        background: red;
        margin-left: 13px;
        width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    li {
        padding: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    } .close {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
        background: red;
        margin-left: 13px;
        width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="header">
    <h2>My To Do List</h2>
    <button onclick="addItem()" class="addBtn" title="Click on me to add the item">+ Add +</button>
    <input type="text" id="listInput" placeholder="Type here">
</div>
<!--list begins-->
<ul id="myList"> </ul>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206402/discussion-between-sohail-and-nfl).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the parent element and append the button using jquery 
like:

```
 $("#parent-div").append("<button class="button-create">Created Button</button>");
```